# Facing Issue in using Scala + Slick + MySQL+ Akka + Stream

Tags: scala, akka, slick, akka-stream

**Problem Statement** : We are adding all incoming request parameters of user for particular module in MySQL DB table as a row (this is a huge data). Now, we want to design a process which will read each record from this table and will get more information about that request of user by calling third party APIs and after that it will put this returned meta information in another table.

**Current Attempts**:

I am using Scala + Slick to do this. As the data to read is huge, I want to read this table one row at a time and process it. I tried using slick + akka streams, however I am getting 'java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException'

Following is the rough logic that I have tried,

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("Example")
import system.dispatcher
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val future = db.stream(SomeQuery.result)
Source.fromPublisher(future).map(row => {
        id = dataEnrichmentAPI.process(row)

}).runForeach(id => println("Processed row : "+ id))
```

**dataEnrichmentAPI.process** : This function makes a third party REST call and also does some DB query to get required data. This DB query is done using 'db.run' method and it also waits until it finishes (Using Await)

e.g.,

```
def process(row: RequestRecord): Int = {
   // SomeQuery2 = Check if data is already there in DB
   val retId: Seq[Int] = Await.result(db.run(SomeQuery2.result), Duration.Inf)
   if(retId.isEmpty){
         val metaData = RestCall()
         // SomeQuery3 = Store this metaData in DB
         Await.result(db.run(SomeQuery3.result), Duration.Inf)
         return metaData.id;      
   }else{
       // SomeQuery4 = Get meta data id 
      return Await.result(db.run(SomeQuery4.result), Duration.Inf)     
   }
 }
```

I am getting this exception where I am using blocking call to DB. I don't think if I can get rid of it as return value is required for later flow to continue.

Does 'blocking call' is a reason behind this Exception ?
What is the best practice to solve this kind of problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't slick 3.0 have support for Akka Streams out of the box?

Comment: yes, it does, that's the reason why I used Source.fromPublisher method of akka library to consume the stream handle given by slick

Comment: why don't you do that in the process method as well then? Instead of the awaits just flapmap over the streams

Comment: @martijn not exactly, it supports http://www.reactive-streams.org/, to use akka streams you have to wrap the `Publisher` with a `Source`

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti let me clarify a bit. What I meant was replace all DB.run with DB.stream and flatmap over them. That doesn't block, await and DB.run do

Comment: @Martjin : DB.run doesn't block, because value return by this method is of type Future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem (too few details) but you should never block.

Speaking of best practices, us [async stages](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#mapasync) instead.
This is more or less what your code would look like without using Await.result:

```
def process(row: RequestRecord): Future[Int] = {
   db.run(SomeQuery2.result) flatMap { 
      case retId if retId.isEmpty =>
        // what is this? is it a sync call? if it's a rest call it should return a future
        val metaData = RestCall() 
        db.run(SomeQuery3.result).map(_ => metaData.id)

      case _ => db.run(SomeQuery4.result)
   }
 }


Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(SomeQuery.result))
  // choose your own parallelism
  .mapAsync(2)(dataEnrichmentAPI.process)
  .runForeach(id => println("Processed row : "+ id))
```

This way you will be handling backpressure and parallelism explicitly and idiomatically.

Try to *never* call Await.result in production code and only [compose futures using map, flatMap and for comprehensions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

Comment: Thanks for your Comment. This process method contains following steps :

     def process(row: RequestRecord): Int = {
       ...Something...
       Await.result(db.run(SomeQuery2.result), Duration.Inf)
       ...Something...
}

Comment: @aks use map/flatmap (or for comprehensions) and make it return a future, never use `Await.result` in production code

Comment: I have updated process method. As you can see there is lots of dependencies in process function to execute require instructions. Hence, I am using this blocking call. Any idea how to get rid of this using AsyncCall.

Comment: @aks I edited the answer to look like your example. Remove _all_ the `Await.result` in your code. Start from the innermost call and make it return a Future[X] instead of blocking, then start composing futures using map/flatmap/for comprehensions http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. I did exactly what you said. I transformed all synchronous calls to async. However I still get same exception. However, when I added Thread.sleep in main method it worked partially. I wonder is there any way to solve this issue apart from calling sleep on main thread.

Comment: @aks sleep in the main thread? is your application a stand-alone app that you run and then terminates?

Comment: Yes its continuously running process, by the way, I am able to resolve the problem by not adding sleep. Idea is not to have any statement to be execute after 'runForeach' method (which will be call when each data returned by stream is consumed ). Once I removed that, it worked. 
However, I am now facing an issue of handling failure case, so what I need is if some error occurs I want to know which data has been process and which has not, so that after fixing the error, I can again continue from that point. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: are you executing it in a while loop?

you have to wait for the stream to terminate before starting another one, you could materialize the next iteration in the onComplete handler of the future of the previous one